# Что значит слово "гой"

Tags: грамотная-речь

*На почестен пир мед-пиво пити мед-пиво пити гостей веселити предков славных чтити да родных по закону сварожьему славити! Слава! Слава! Слава! Гой!*

А теперь другое применение Слова "гой"

Под Берёзкой устанавливают Яруна (того самого, коего привёз в своё время Ярила Вешний), либо — тут же сплетённую из соломы куклу Ярилы с ярко выраженным мужским достоинством — гоем, искусно вырезанным из дубового сука и окрашенным в красный цвет. Водят вокруг Берёзки хороводы, поют песни, парни выкликают девушек на пляс посередь круга — коло Берёзки-Лели да Гоя - Ярилы. Внезапно кто-то из плясунов опрокидывает Яруна

Я поначалу воспринимал Гой как торжественный возглас, в завершении каждой прославляющей речи, как бы созвучно фразе - "Да будет так", но потом "достоинством - гоем" и "Гоя - Ярилы" меня ввело в заблуждение. Что бы это значило?, но если применить такое слово как возглас звучащий в виде "Утверждения" тогда оно может принимать и оборотные значения.

но Иудеи применили его иначе читаем:
В талмудическом законе «Орах-хайим 55,20» гои сравниваются с навозом и калом (стр. 50-51).
Затем гои приравниваются к собакам (стр. 65). и т.д.

И так, что это слово означало для славян я вроде как разобрался. Дело в другом,  частое употребление данного слова,  а славяне совершали много обрядов и оно было на слуху, приобрело на мой взгляд у иудеев для славян - имя нарицательное "Гои". К примеру, человек который заикается называют "Заика". Если для славян начертано имя нарицательное ГОЙ, то писания отправляют читателя адресно к конкретному народу.

Христиане переводя Иудейское учение на кириллицу интерпретировали "Гои" как "Языце", а затем "Язычник".

Помогите найти истину.

Прибегнув к "Словенице" получил расшифровку понятий этого слова и привел примеры расшифровки других.

ҕ - Гервь (гха). Неизведанное, но проявленное, благость, состояние человека в момент просветления. Данная буквица всегда прописывалась в т.н. удивительных формах (ныне - восклицательных) и использовалась для выражения, обозначения чего-то удивительного, чудесного, но, одновременно, и непонятного; то, что не определялось каким-то характерным признаком, но данный образ невозможно было описать. Раньше было две формы – удивительная ! и вопросительная ?. Проявление идет либо из Нави, Слави или Прави, т.е. оно явлено из других Мiров, что считалось божественным знаком, чудом. А т.к. божественное нельзя выразить в какой-то определенной форме, то и числового значения буквица «гервь» не имела. Но иногда удивительное нельзя было описать глаголом, тогда буквица принимала форму Дервь. Добро рекомое свыше. Гхарный хлопец - это не хороший, это необычный хлопец. Гханя - необычная девочка.

г - Глаголи (г). Движение, истечение, направление, передача знания от истока. Когда человек глаголит, он направляет свою мысль на кого-то или на что-то, т.е. передача информации осуществляется по следующей схеме: излучатель (уста) - поток звуковой информации (речь, глаголение) - приемник (уши). И одновременно, глагол подразумевал тройственность: передача звуковой формы, образной формы и сокрытой (тайной) формы, т.е. мысли.

о - (онъ)Некто, нечто, что-то, находящееся в особом состоянии, отделенное от земного, но для нас уже проявленное. Мы небесное отделяем от земного, священное отделяем от земного и многомерное отделяем от нашего мира. Но, в то же время, мы и определяем: данная сфера (О) - нечто не нашего мира (N), сотворенная и проявленная (Ъ) - ОНЪ (он). Т.о., ОН - форма не нашего внутреннего мира, но имеющая некую связь с нами.

Ѭ- Ота (о кр.). Неприятие чего-либо неизвестного, но существующего (непознанная, вопросительная форма). То, что необходимо изучить и принять решение.
Познание того, что неприемлемо, укрепляет Дух.

Є- Есть (е). Форма существования Бытия (быть); нахождение в данной реальности; нахождение в проявленном состоянии; то, что имеет объем и восприятие, зримое и чувственное. Одновременно, это означает и то, что находится в развитии.
Е- Есмь (йе). Разнообразие, многоплановость, многомерность, многоструктурность, многозадачность, обсуждение и рассуждение, применительно к определенной точке обсуждения (точкой может быть ВСЕ).

(Ъ - Ер (о кр.). Твёрдость в понятии утверждения какого-то действа, происходящего под определенным управлением (выполнение необходимого действия - сотворяша).
ПОСТЪ - Полное Очищение Собственных Телес сотворяша. )

ᴂ - Ижа (й). Oтражает характеристику движения времени (меру времени).
(м ᴂ (й)р)- самая малая частица времени, которой пользовались наши предки. Фонетически она звучит кратко, сжато: «понятие объёмности, взаимосочетания. Кроме того, данная буквица использовалась для показа структур-антиподов (белое-черное, время-пространство). Заметьте, даже в мйр», т.к. ижа произносилась как « и-краткое» (й). И в то же время она делится, измеряет, дает начертании буквицы отражен принцип зеркальности: д+е. Поэтому наш мир (бытие) - это структура размеренная, большая (е) - «макромир». А другой, напротив, маленький (д) - «микромир». Эта структура . отмечена, как бы, и временем, и сочетанием.

ї - Инить (и). С двумя точками на верху, которая указывает на ограниченность пространства:гармония наша истинна, утвержденная и сотворенная, т.е. уже приведенная в определенный порядок. Слово наша (а не мое, не её), т.е. общее, множественное. Т.о. Инить передавала образ единого много-сферного (общинного) определения: общие характеристики, формы, правила, устои.

і - Ижеи (и). Истинную жизнь бытия гармонизирует со Вселенной. Вертикальная линия - связь небесного и земного; точка - вышнее. Проявленный энерго-информационный поток. Поэтому образ показывает связь с вышним, вышней (изначальной) точкой, и данный образ этой буквицы использовался для определения вселенских масштабов (во вселенском большом и во вселенском малом).

И - Иже (и). Соединение, союз, единство, гармония, равновесие, то, что удерживает цельность самой жизни. Все пути сошлись в одной точке, и они гармоничные. Поэтому числовое значение - 8. Образ ИЖЕ: уравновешивающая (гармонизирующая) жизнь бытия. Это - союзная форма.

Ҙ- Земля (з). Вселенская структура, многомерная форма: то, что входит в определенную систему как составная часть; то, с чем жизнь контактирует, соприкасается; планета.

Ȿ - Дзело (дз). Означает не только весьма, сверх, много, но и то, что находится сверх нашего понимания; за гранью нашего сознания и воображения; то, что нам еще не ведомо и то, что мы еще не познали. Иначе говоря, всё находящееся вне рамок восприятия, таинственное, запредельное, божественная форма. Оно, как бы, взаимосвязано, проистекает (существует), но для понимания оного необходимо подниматься над самим собой сегодняшним, т.е. развиваться. Оно, как таковое, не закрыто для нашего понимания, оно само также должно развиваться опережающими темпами, чтобы превосходить наш завтрашний уровень познания. Расширение меры понимания и уровня осознанности.

Ѩ - Арь (а кр., я). Oднородная структура. Взаимосвязь небесного (i) и земного (а), но взаимосвязь очень тонкая (соприкосновение), где каждое существует само по себе, хотя это понятия одного рода.

Теперь мы пишем два слова Гой (Ҕо Є), Изгой (ї Ȿг Ѭ ᴂ) и читаем смысл:

Гой (Ҕо Є) звучащее как (гхое)

Ҕ - состояние человека в момент просветления

О - находящегося в особом состоянии

Є  - Форма существования Бытия (быть)

Изгой (ї Ȿг Ѭ ᴂ) звучащее как (идзгой)

ї - Инить передавала образ единого много-сферного (общинного) определения: общие характеристики, формы, правила, устои.

Ȿ - Означает не только весьма, сверх, много, но и то, что находится сверх нашего понимания; за гранью нашего сознания и воображения.

г - одновременно, глагол подразумевал тройственность: передача звуковой формы, образной формы и сокрытой (тайной) формы, т.е. мысли.

Ѭ - форма не нашего внутреннего мира, но имеющая некую связь с нами

ᴂ - определяет меру (единицу времени) в данном случае относится к мере вины зеркально противоположное к мере ответственности.

Далее:
Гей (Ге ᴂ) - звучит как (г(йе)й)

г - одновременно, глагол подразумевал тройственность: передача звуковой формы, образной формы и сокрытой (тайной) формы, т.е. мысли.

е - Разнообразие, обсуждение и рассуждение, применительно к определенной точке обсуждения

ᴂ - определяет меру,  в данном случае меру различия, зеркальность буквицы так же использовалась для показа структур-антиподов.

Гея (ГЄѨ) звучит как (Гея)

г - одновременно, глагол подразумевал тройственность: передача звуковой формы, образной формы и сокрытой (тайной) формы, т.е. мысли.

Є  - Форма существования Бытия (быть)

Ѩ - Oднородная структура. Взаимосвязь небесного (i) и земного (а), но взаимосвязь очень тонкая (соприкосновение), где каждое существует само по себе, хотя это понятия одного рода.

Comment: Надо спрашивать не у славян. Это слово — не самоназвание. И не следует писать цитату прописными. Их у вас в тексте и так перебор.

Comment: Не могли бы вы сюда добавить ссылку на талмудический закон «Орах-хайим» 55 20 и 60?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Гой еси" - древнеславянское выражение, имеющее приветственно-пожелательную форму, как слово "Здравствуй!".
Древнерусское"гой" означает жизнь, здоровье, жизненную силу. Например, в словаре Даля, гоить — стар.слав «говеть, жить, здравствовать». Гой - жизнь, жить; Изгой - из жизни, изжитый.

Исходя из последнего заключения, некоторые исследователи словоформулу "гой еси" трактуют немного иначе. Если рассматривать с этой стороны, то "гой еси" означает ровно противоположное "изгою" значение, то есть признание принадлежности роду, племени. Еси - глагол-связка, означающее «быть» или «будь».

Некоторые исследователи идут дальше. Они считают, что гой - это не только жизнь и живительная сила, но и животворящая сила, или по попросту говоря - фаллический образ, который относится напрямую к мужскому роду. Этому есть некоторые подтверждения. Например, ни в одной древнеславянской сказке, былине, сказании и т.д., выражение "гой еси" не относится к женщине, только к "добрым молодцам", рекам, Земле, лесам, Руси и так далее. Однако последнее утверждение не является достоверным на 100% и является только предположением историка Бориса Рыбакова и некоторых других.

В "официальном" контексте это выражение носит именно приветственную форму, в котором подразумевается пожелание жизни и здоровья

С ивритом ничего общего не имеет.

В переводе с иврита слово «гой» означает — «народ» (любой). В том числе — и еврейский.Именно в этом значении («еврейский народ») оно довольно часто употребляется в  первоисточниках. В Торе (в частности, в Пятикнижии и Танахе) оно используется, как минимум, раз пятьсот. И в половине встречающихся случаев — в значении «еврейский народ».К примеру, в книге Дварим (гл. 4, ст. 34) о создании еврейского народа написано: «...лаках ло гой ми-керев гой» — «И взял (Всевышний) гоя из среды (другого) гоя (и возложил на него особые задачи»). То есть — «взял еврейский народ (гой) из среды другого народа (гоя — египетского народа)», в среде которого мы жили около 200-т лет.

Некоторые усматривают в слове "изгой" ивритские корни: гой-принадлежит народу, изгой-изгнанный из народа, но мне кажется версия "изгой-лишённый жизни, изжитый"более правдоподобной, ведь изгой - оттенок "одинокий и несчастный"

Comment: Людмила, огромное спасибо. Лучшего ответа я и не ожидал.

Answer (score -2):

Полным абсурдом выглядят попытки объяснить изначальный смысл русского слова с помощью его производных - инородных наречий и диалектов. На нашей Мидгард-Земле был и есть только один единственный ЯЗЫК - Хранитель Изначальных Смыслов Слов, что есть его главной функцией, а также это ЯЗЫК межгалактического и межвселенского общения разумных существ. Это - русский язык, а точнее - древнерусский. Есть слово-аббревиатура - РАСА, что означает, как говорили наши Светлые Боги в Славяно-Арийских ВЕДАХ: "Роды Расы Великой и потомки Рода Небесного" - два Рода Арийский: даарийцы и харийцы, и два Рода Славянских: святорусы и рассены. Каждый из них дал человечеству свой основной вид письменности: даарийцы - Тьраги, от которых произошли все иероглифы и арабские письмена; харийцы - Каруну - Союз Рун = 244 руны, из которых только десятой частью пользовались скандинавы и германцы; святорусы - Буквицу и рассены - Зеркально-Образные письмена - Молвицу. А всего у нас было 9 видов письменности. Сейчас наиболее понятная и близкая к современному русскому языку - это Буквица. В отличие от современного без-образного, обрезанного и искажённого языка, Буквица имеет 49 буквиц и множество образов для каждой буквицы. Это то, что раньше называлось азбукой.
Почему же именно русская письменность является изначальной и единственной на Мидгард-земле? Во-первых, потому что наши Предки раньше всех других народов заселили эту планету 1,5 миллиарда лет назад. А во-вторых, потому что только русский язык отвечает смыслу самого слова ЯЗЫК - Азъ/Енъ/Арь - ЗЫ - К, где Азъ - человек-бог на земле, Енъ - образное мировосприятие и скоростное мышление, которые были у наших великих Предков; Арь - ОдноРодность с Божественным потоком и Изначальным; ЗЫ - приЗЫв; К - расКрытие. Буквы Я нет в Буквице, вместо неё использовали Азъ, Енъ или Арь, т.е. правильнее писать АЗЫК. Таким образом, ЯЗЫК - это призыв к раскрытию в себе: Образного мировосприятия и скоростного мышления; однородности с Изначальным и Божественным потоком; бога на земле. АЗБУКА = А-З-Бу-КА, где А - Источник, З - Знания, Бу - Буква, КА - Дух. Таким образом, АЗБУКА =  "Источник Знаний - Дух Буквы". И это действительно так - как мы можем узнать суть слова, не зная сути букв его составляющих? В-третьих, наш мир и все иные Миры, Галактики и Вселенные были сотворены нашими Светлыми Богами.
Теперь разберём слово ГОЙ. Г-О-Й, где Г - Глаголи - поток знаний, О - Онъ - Божественное, связь с Богом; Й - Иже краткое - вспышка, озарение, "обрати внимание". Таким образом, ГОЙ - это "Поток Божественных Знаний, на которые надо обратить внимание". Когда трудно было определить изначальный смысл слова, наши Предки читали его с обратной стороны, тогда "ГОЙ" наоборот, получается "ЙОГ". Кто такой йог? Это человек, направляющий своё внимание - самый важный ресурс человека, на свой внутренний мир, концентрируясь на своих внутренних ощущениях. Тогда ЙОГ наоборот, будет ГОЙ - человек, концентрирующийся на знаках внешнего мира, устанавливая связь с Богами и получая от Них знаки и важную информацию. Т.е., если ГОЙ стоит в начале предложения, то это призыв направить своё внимание на дальнейшее повествование, в котором будет присутствовать Божественное знание.
Слово ЕСИ означало простое "есть", это легко увидеть в Ведах, в обращениях к Богам, в конце которых часто употребляется выражение: "Тако бысть тако еси тако буди", что означает - "так было, так есть и так будет". Поэтому при употреблении слов ГОЙ ЕСИ, при обращении к кому-то, это означает пожелание этому человеку быть ГОЕМ, т.е. тем, кто умеет управлять своим вниманием, чтобы видеть и понимать знаки вселенной,  сохранять связь с Богами и получать от Них нужную и важную информацию, божественное знание.
Тогда ИЗ-ГОЙ означает того, кто перестал быть ГОЕМ, как бы вышел ИЗ этого состояния ГОЯ - направленности внимания на окружающий мир.